# Better support for controlling printing options like headers and footers from Javascript

Tags: browser

Why is it that browsers do not provide a mecanism to set the printing defaults regarding headers and footers from within the app?

Web apps are fully fledged apps nowadays, and modern browsers are capable of sending a very well formatted page to a printer (or even download it as a PDF), but web apps cannot rely on this method because browsers don't allow them to control the metadata completely.

Current possibilities don't allow websites to store the printing settings along with the  report or file on the server.

Each browser provides it's own mandatory dialog form to set printing settings that could be replaced when needed by a more convenient experience: in-app options, adapted to the use case, cloud-persistent and consistent along different browsers.

The options that are currently available are:

1. Delegating part of the work on the user (i.e., having him/her change the metadata options and paper size/orientation themselves).
2. Using other methods that can quickly become too expensive and complicated, like generating PDF's on the server for the user to download.

Opting for number 1 is not always our decision.  As professional web developers, the final users are usually not our direct clients, but our client's target audience.  Also, we would be forcing the final user to do extra work.  Experience says that it wouldn't be done and reports will be printed with the default settings of the browser, usually with headers and footers that the user don't really want (and the associated paper waste if he/she decides to print it againg without them).

Option 2 --generating server side PDF's-- is becoming less of an option every day.  Modern web apps are heavy users of javascript, and reports benefit from excellent plotting libraries made with JS that can generate charts in HTML canvas elements that could be printed right away if we weren't using this "do it all over again on the server" approach.
The resulting reports never look the same, and programmers have to maintain two versions of every report.
Moreover, generating PDF's on the server can be really slow and resource consuming.

So, is there a compelling reason why browsers programmers opted not to support this kind of customization?

Comment: I might understand headers and footers, but why do you want to mess with my default printer settings? Who knows best what kind of paper I have in my printer's tray, you or me?

Comment: "avoid asking subjective questions where … your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”" ([help/dont-ask]) See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: I didn't think about the rant side of the question.  It's true that it frustrates me, but I will edit it and I'm sure that it will became a very valid question.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau It's not that the web app should change your general settings, just those for the current print.  Why?  Because sometimes the browser don't give you enough control and you really need it.  Consider a website that allows you to save the selected paper size along with the file you're editing, like Word does.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau (just to clarify) What I am asking for is a way to let THE USERS select the paper size in a more convenient way (in-app, adapted to the use case and server-persistent) that the one browsers currently provide.

Comment: Word was built from square one to work within a particular page configuration.  Forcing a document into that is beyond the scope of what HTML was designed to do.

Comment: @Blrfl All current uses of HTML excede what it was designed to do.  HTML's survival merit resides on it's historical capability to be extended.  Anyway, I truly don't want this to become a troll, If you really think that browsers should keep not supporting customization just answer the question telling why.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that HTML is a markup language, not a page description language.  The browser still has final say over the layout.

Comment: Again:  I don't want to force the browser to do anything.  I only want to suggest a setting to come preloaded in the dialog for the current page.  A setting that the user may prefer over the global one, given the use case.

Comment: It's nothing that current server side PDF generation approach doesn't do already, but it would make our life a lot easier this way.

Comment: I already edited the question, please revise the moderation.  The accepted answer is very constructive and non opinionated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a definite tension between designs appropriate for interactive use and those that look good on the printed page. All of the interactive functions that have evolved into HTML pages/apps (e.g. forms, buttons, navigational controls, dynamic AJAX data loads, and interactivity) do not rest well on a static piece of paper. The print-outs of many web pages positively screams "I am a printed web page! I was not designed to be printed!"

But that doesn't mean it can't work. Most of the sites that really care about printed output have a separate printer icon that generates a "designed to be printed page." That requires some extra programming, but is generally manageable with templated output.

Modern CSS has an `@media` that designates what output realm a CSS rule apples to. Different CSS style sheets can be imported for screen and print:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen,print">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="paper.css" media="print">
```

Or you can designate rules directly inside a stylesheet, like so:

```
@media screen {
    body { 
        background-color: green; 
        margin: 20px;
    }
    p {
        font-family: verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media print {

    @page {
        size: letter portrait;
        margin: 0mm;
    }
    body { 
        background-color: white; 
        margin: 1in;
    }
    p {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: black;
    }
}
```

Note the `@page` selector sets page size, orientation, and margins. There are specific mechanisms for handling first pages, left pages, and right pages; for managing pagination (where page breaks occur, how widows and orphans are managed, etc.) On some browsers (Chrome and Opera e.g., and possibly Firefox, setting the page margin to 0 will eliminate the annoying automatically supplied headers and footers you mentioned. But like all things Web, this is browser-specific. On some browsers (looking at you, IE!), the user may need to turn off those embellishments when printing. Microsoft products also seem to obey some Microsoft-specific page controls such as `mso-header-margin`, `mso-footer-margin`, and `mso-paper-source` which might help you squelch undesirable extras.

So, long story short, good browser support for printing is feasible and available. CSS's page-oriented design features don't have 100% the precision of a word processing or page layout format, but they're pretty close. They should be more commonly used.

Here is [the relevant CSS3 specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-page/), [a good quick overview of the @page rule](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm), and [a good article on how to set up a print style sheet](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/).

Comment: So... it turns out that it's all already customizable except headers and footers (at least in a consistent way), right?

Comment: More on the subject of margins: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2780518/290221
(info on how different browsers behave)

Comment: Yes, most of the things you wanted (control of the page shape, orientation, etc.) and need (pagination) are customizable via CSS. Chrome and Opera handle those specs very nicely; Firefox and IE, less so (if only because it's harder to squelch unwanted/unneeded headers/footers). It might be possible to create shims to hide IE/Firefox headers/footers (e.g. white boxes that overlay them), though haven't seen pre-made versions.

Comment: Also, a helpful trick: as an alternative to generating a new window with printable content, some of my apps simply delete all the UI/interactive controls, or make them invisible. That's a single jQuery statement, and it leaves a page that is essentially pure content--thus ready for printing.

Comment: I believe you can also set them to `display:none` in the printed media stylesheet.

Comment: You can set `display: none`, `visibility: collapse` (for table rows), or `visibility: hidden`. The first two change the layout, acting as though the items aren't there. `visibility: hidden` is useful when you want the spacing/layout to remain constant, but some things just not appear. Deleting the items is like `display: none`, but also provides a cleaner DOM. It all depends on how you're going to use the resulting HTML. For printing alone, `display` and `visibility` may suffice; if you're also preparing for cut-and-paste (say for copying content to other apps), deletion can be superior.